# PhpStorm : Darcula theme shows white background

Tags: phpstorm

I'm not sure what has happened, but this morning when I opened PhpStorm the background of the editor is now white even though the selected theme is still Darcula - any idea? It was all good last night - but now it's all white.

[image]

Comment: As others have already said: there are 2 places where you need to choose Darcula to have complete dark IDE: GUI Theme and Editor Scheme (syntax colors etc). If you are the only person who uses this computer and you do not remember changing anything like that .. it could be a bug in IDE. What PhpStorm version do you have there?

Comment: I'm on the latest version 9.0.2 - and have never had this problem before (I've been using PHPStorm for well over a year).

Comment: Me two until 9.0.x. I mean -- I do not have the same issue as you do -- mine is a bit different -- if I edit my keymap or some other setting .. after restart it all gone (file with custom settings gets physically deleted on next IDE launch). For me it was fixed in 9.5 EAP builds.

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne - this probably indicates that there is some issue with the IDE. I've noticed that theme files were physically removed with each reboot - really strange.

Answer (score 32):

You are looking in the wrong place. The background color (and the code colors) is not determined by the **theme**, but by the **scheme**.

You can choose the scheme by going to `Editor > Colors & Fonts`:

[image]

You also have a preview of how the scheme will look like on every file type:

[image]

Comment: I did that, but what I don't understand is why did it change in the first place - yesterday it was all ok and today it's just all mess.

Comment: I can't think of any thing. It's probably a bug in PhpStorm or someone worked on your computer...

Comment: Thanks! Works great! Any idea hot to change the Terminal background as well?

Comment: @Raptor The Terminal colors should also be determined by the scheme (at least its background color).
Note that the currently open Terminal tabs **won't** be affected when you change the scheme (but new ones will).

Answer (score 7):

You have to set "scheme" in "editor->colors and fonts" to darcula.
There are several other dark editor schemes you could try.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Preferences -> Colors & Fonts -> General -> Default Text -> Background Color and uncheck the inheritance box and select your color.

I had the same problem when I installed the new PHPStorm V10.